# ¿Cómo hago para ingresar un arreglo de 7 elementos y que me lo ordene por el método de intercambio?

Tags: c++, array

He logrado hacer esto: cuando ingreso 7 números del 1 al 7 me anda, pero cuando  ingreso números mas grandes no me funciona.. por qué? 
Acá les dejo el código  que he hecho hasta el momento.. agradecería su ayuda.. La duda que tengo es: en qué parte del código debería pedirle al usuario que ingrese los números y en qué variables debería guardarlo? Y también en ¿Cómo haría para imprimir esos números que el usuario me ingrese? ahí es donde estoy perdido, en la parte donde tengo que pedir que me ingrese los números.

```
#include <iostream>


void intercambiar(int& x, int& y) {

int aux = x;
x = y;
y = aux; 

}


//Ordenamiento por Intercambio Ascendente

void ordIntercambio(int a[], int n) {

  int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
     for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {      
        if (a[i] < a[j]) {

        intercambiar(a[i], a[j]);
        }
    }
}

}


void imprimirArreglo(int a[], int tam) {

std::cout << "[";

for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {

std::cout << a[i] << ","; }

std::cout << "]" << std::endl; } 

void copiar_arreglo(int origen[], int destino[], int tam){

for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {

destino[i] = origen[i];  } }  

int main() {

int tamArreglo = 6;

int arregloOrg[6];

int arregloTemporal[6];

for(int i=0; i<7;i++){

std::cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";

std:: cin >>arregloOrg[i];  }

std::cout << "Arreglo a ordenar: " << std::endl;

imprimirArreglo (arregloOrg, tamArreglo);

std::cout << std::endl;

//copio el arreglo para tener una version del original...

copiar_arreglo(arregloOrg, arregloTemporal, tamArreglo);

ordIntercambio(arregloTemporal, tamArreglo);

std::cout << "Ordenamiento por Intercambio Ascendente: " << std::endl;

imprimirArreglo(arregloTemporal, tamArreglo);

std::cout << std::endl;

return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el fallo es que los arreglos los defines de 6 elementos, pero luego a la hora de ingresarlos ingresas 7. Así, el último no lo considera. Y entiendo que quieres que el tamaño de los arreglos sea de 7 elementos, no de 6.

Ten en cuenta que un array de x elementos se define como `array[x]` , aunque se recorra desde `array[0]` hasta `array[x-1]`

Te pongo tu propio código con un mínimo cambio. Solo he sacado el tamaño del array a una constante para que todos las partes que hagan uso de él sean referenciados a esa constante, de forma que solo cambiando ese valor sea fácil que el programa funcione con cualquier tamaño de array, y un pequeño cambio en la función imprimir para que no muestre la última coma:

```
#include <iostream>


void intercambiar(int& x, int& y)
{
    int aux = x;
    x = y;
    y = aux;
}


//Ordenamiento por Intercambio Ascendente

void ordIntercambio(int a[], int n)
{

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] < a[j])
            {

                intercambiar(a[i], a[j]);
            }
        }
    }

}


void imprimirArreglo(int a[], int tam)
{

    std::cout << "[";

    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {

        std::cout << a[i];
        if (i<tam-1)
        {
            std::cout<< ",";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
}

void copiar_arreglo(int origen[], int destino[], int tam)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {

        destino[i] = origen[i];
    }
}

const int TAM = 7;

int main()
{

    int tamArreglo = TAM;

    int arregloOrg[TAM];

    int arregloTemporal[TAM];

    for(int i=0; i<TAM; i++)
    {

        std::cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";

        std:: cin >>arregloOrg[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Arreglo a ordenar: " << std::endl;

    imprimirArreglo (arregloOrg, tamArreglo);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    //copio el arreglo para tener una version del original...

    copiar_arreglo(arregloOrg, arregloTemporal, tamArreglo);

    ordIntercambio(arregloTemporal, tamArreglo);

    std::cout << "Ordenamiento por Intercambio Ascendente: " << std::endl;

    imprimirArreglo(arregloTemporal, tamArreglo);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```